# Закрыть активность с намерением. Андроид

Tags: java, android

Имеются 3 активности `А > B > C;` Далее хочу вернуться в активность `В < C;` с намерением выполнить перезагрузку `В - onRefresh();`
Пробовал так из `С` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent( C.this, B.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

И в активности `В` `onCreate`:

```
 if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        onRefresh();
    }
```

Но такой подход очищает и активность `B`.
Как вызвать `onRefresh();` при закрытии активности `C` не очищая активность `В`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю для этого подойдет `onActivityResult()`

Конкретно на вашем примере в активности **В** вызов активности **С** должен происходить как то так

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
..
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCESS_TYPE);
```

Так же в активности **В** должен быть переопределен метод `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_ACCESS_TYPE) {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_REFRESH) {
            onRefresh();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

И наконец в активности **С** перед ее закрытием мы посылаем `RESULT_REFRESH` - Активность **С** закрывается, а **В** в свою очередь остается прежней и получив `RESULT_REFRESH` выполнит `onRefresh()`

```
setResult(RESULT_REFRESH);
finish();
```

***UPD***

Так же можно куда то записывать `boolean` флаг для рефреша перед завершением активности **С** (например `SharedPreferences` или прости статическую переменную), а в активности **В** в методе `onResume()` смотреть если флаг `true`, то 'выключаем' его (`false`) и выполняем `onRefresh()`

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ , метод  `onActivityResult` мне подошёл. Всё работает.